# Highcharts line only displaying dots?

Tags: highcharts

I need to use a "name" attribute for the X axis, so I can put the name of the month. 
I can not therefore use an array of values within the `data` attribute. So I can not use something of this kind `data:[12,13,45]`;

Using something like this:

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
      series: [{
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Septiembre',
            y: 1687
        }, {
            name: 'Octubre',
            y: 2085
        }]
    }],
});
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/9kwa3q1s/1/)

[image]

Comment: without `colorByPoint: true,` reproduction https://jsfiddle.net/9kwa3q1s/2/

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the question here. Please describe what specifically you want to change in your chart.